# Not able to open screen in reactjs.Routing not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react and trying below link to get started.

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/09/11/react-basic-http-authentication-tutorial-example

But, my screen is not showing any thing and there is not such error on CLI after npm start.

Below is index.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { App } from './App/App.js';

// setup fake backend
import { configureFakeBackend } from './_helpers/fake-backend.js';
configureFakeBackend();

render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

App.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

    import { PrivateRoute } from '../_components/PrivateRoute.js';
    import { HomePage } from '../HomePage/Homepage.js';
    import { LoginPage } from '../LoginPage';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="jumbotron">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <Router>
                            <div>
                                <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                                <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
                            </div>
                        </Router>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { App };
```

It is just opening a blank half opened screen.

Below is CLI screen shot.

[image]

Below are home and login.js code.

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { userService } from '../_services/user.service.js';

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: {},
            users: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ 
            user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')),
            users: { loading: true }
        });
        userService.getAll().then(users => this.setState({ users }));
    }

    render() {
        const { user, users } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                alert("I am  2nd here");
                <h1 >Hi {user.firstName}!</h1>
                <p>You're logged in with React & Basic HTTP Authentication!!</p>
                <h3>Users from secure api end point:</h3>
                {users.loading && <em>Loading users...</em>}
                {users.length &&
                    <ul>
                        {users.map((user, index) =>
                            <li key={user.id}>
                                {user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}
                            </li>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                }
                <p>
                    <Link to="/login">Logout</Link>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { HomePage };
```

And output screen is :
[image]

Comment: are you returning the component HomePage in PrivatRoute, can you add the PrivateRoute hoc component

Comment: i think the first three div in App only is rendered, also try hitting in the url as localhost:8000/login check whether login component is rendering, i think some thing wrong in the PrivateComponent. Kindly post the remaining code so it will be helpful to find the issue

Comment: Can you share PrivateRoute.js code

Comment: import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute =({component : Component , ...rest })=> 
(
    <Route {...rest} render = {props =>(
        localStorage.getItem('user'
        ?<Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to = {{pathname : '/login' , state : { from : props.location}} } />
        )
    )} />
)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS with localhost:8080/login I am getting

 cannot GET / login 
message

Comment: is the react is running in 8080 or 3000 are you using create react app

Comment: I am using npm start. and 8080

Comment: When I directly write  <LoginPage /> like this then I can see the login html atleast.
So i guess my Privateroute and Route are not working

Comment: Thanks guys I have managed to solve it.There was issue in PrivateRoute if else condition handling.Yoc can compare with right one below. Check out () carefully between ? and :
 import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute =({component : Component , ...rest })=> 
(
    <Route {...rest} render = {props =>(
        localStorage.getItem("user")
        ? (
        <Component {...props} />)
        : (<Redirect to = {{pathname : '/login' , state : { from : props.location}} } />
        )
    )} />
)